# Filter not working in Yii CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii. I am displaying some data in my view. I have added filters in my View, But it seems not working. Please help me solving this.

My View:

```
<?php
/* @var $this NimsoftHostsDetailsController */
/* @var $model NimsoftHostsDetails */
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Nimsoft Hosts Details'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Create NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('label'=>'Update NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('label'=>'Delete NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('label'=>'Manage NimsoftHostsDetails', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>View NimsoftHostsDetails - </h1><h3><?php echo "Host Name - ".$host_name;?></h3>
<?php 
      if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error'))
        {
        echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error');
        }
?> 

<!--<a href="<?php //echo $this->createUrl('/NimsoftHostsDetails/create?id='.$host_id);?>" title="Add Date Entry" class="btn btn-primary circle_ok" style="text-decoration: none;" >Add Date Entry</a>-->
<a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('/Nimsoft/search_host1?id='.$cust_id);?>" title="Back" class="btn btn-primary circle_ok" style="text-decoration: none;" >Back</a>
<?php /*$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); */?>
<div class="form">
<div class="row">
    <div style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <?php
    $host_id = $host_id;
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'nimsoft-hosts-details-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float:left;"><?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'host_start_date'); ?>
        <?php
                Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
            $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker', array(
            'attribute' => 'host_start_date',
            'language' => '',
            'model' => $model,
            'options' => array(
            'mode' => 'focus',
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'minDate'=>'0',
            'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
            'style'=>'height:20px;',
            'value' => $host_start_date,

            ),
            ));
            ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'host_start_date'); ?></div>
<div style="float:left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'host_end_date'); ?>
    <?php
                Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
            $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker', array(
            'attribute' => 'host_end_date',
            'language' => '',
            'model' => $model,
            'options' => array(
            'mode' => 'focus',
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'minDate'=>'0',
            'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
            'style'=>'height:20px;',
            'value' => $host_end_date,

            ),
            ));
            ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'host_end_date'); ?>
</div>
</div>
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>     
<?php 

$obj=$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ////'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'\'changeTRColor()\'',
    //'itemView'=>'_view',
        'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(

                array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                            'name'=>'host_start_date',
                                            'value'=>'$data->host_start_date',
                ),
                array(
                            'name'=>'host_end_date',
                            'value'=>'$data->host_end_date',
                ),
                array(
                                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                                    'template'=>'{update}{delete}',
                                    )
                ),

)); 

?>
    <?php //echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

class NimsoftHostsDetailsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
     * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/ticket_console';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
            $host_id=$id;
            $model1=new NimsoftHostsDetails;
            $detail = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_id'=>$id));
            if(isset($_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails']))
        {
                        $model1->attributes = $_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails'];
                        $model1->host_id=$id;
                        /*$model=new NimsoftHostsDetails;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails'];
                        $model->host_id=$id;
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                        $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$model->host_start_date,'host_end_date'=>$model->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        if($date_details)
                        {echo "Hi";
                        //Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "DATA already present, Please Enter different Date");
                        //$this->render('view',array('message'=>"DATA already present, Please Enter different Date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();
                        }

                        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                        $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$model->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        if($date_details)
                        {
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('a', "The End date ".$model->host_end_date." is already mentioned as a start date");
                            //$this->render('exist',array('message'=>"The End date ".$model->host_end_date." is already mentioned as a start date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();

                        }



                        if($model->host_start_date == $model->host_end_date)
                        {
                            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('s', "Both dates same, Please Enter different Date");
                            //$this->render('exist',array('message'=>"Both dates same, Please Enter different Date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();
                        }*/
                        if($model1->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model1->host_id));
        }
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "host_id = '$id'";
            $details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $model=new NimsoftHost;
            $detail2 = NimsoftHost::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_id'=>$id));
            foreach($detail2 as $val)
                {
                   $name=$val->host_name;
                   $id=$val->host_id;
                   $cust_id=$val->host_customer_id;

                }
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftHostsDetails',array(
            'criteria'   => $criteria,));
            $this->render('view',array(
                'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'host_name'=>$name,
                'host_id'=>$id,
                'cust_id'=>$cust_id,'model'=>$model1
        ));

    }
/**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate($id)
    {
            $model=new NimsoftHostsDetails;
                $host_id=$id;
        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails'];
                        $model->host_id=$id;

                        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                        $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$model->host_start_date,'host_end_date'=>$model->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        if($date_details)
                        {
                            $this->render('exist',array('message'=>"DATA already present, Please Enter different Date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();

                        }

                        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
                        $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$model->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        if($date_details)
                        {
                            $this->render('exist',array('message'=>"The End date ".$model->host_end_date." is already mentioned as a start date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();

                        }



                        if($model->host_start_date == $model->host_end_date)
                        {
                            $this->render('exist',array('message'=>"Both dates same, Please Enter different Date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
                        die();
                        }
                        if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->host_id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
                    'host_id'=>$host_id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->host_id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('NimsoftHostsDetails');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new NimsoftHostsDetails('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['NimsoftHostsDetails']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['NimsoftHostsDetails'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return NimsoftHostsDetails the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param NimsoftHostsDetails $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='nimsoft-hosts-details-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "mst_nimsoft_hosts_details".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'mst_nimsoft_hosts_details':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $host_id
 * @property string $host_start_date
 * @property string $host_end_date
 */
class NimsoftHostsDetails extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'mst_nimsoft_hosts_details';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
                    array('host_start_date, host_end_date', 'required'),
                    //array('host_start_date','date_validate'),
            array('host_start_date, host_end_date', 'date','format'=>array('yyyy-MM-dd H:m','yyyy-MM-dd H:m')),
            array('host_end_date','compare','compareAttribute'=>'host_start_date','operator'=>'>', 'allowEmpty'=>false,'message'=>'{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".'),
                        //array('host_start_date,host_end_date', 'unique','message'=>'HOST Date already exists!'),
                        // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('host_start_date, host_end_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
                );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'host_id' => 'Host',
            'host_start_date' => 'Host Start Date',
            'host_end_date' => 'Host End Date',
        );
    }

        public function date_validate($attribute)
        {
            $this->host_start_date;
            $this->host_end_date;
            $model=new NimsoftHostsDetails;
            $model->attributes=$_POST['NimsoftHostsDetails'];
            $model->host_id=$id;
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$this->host_start_date,'host_end_date'=>$this->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
            if($date_details)
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'DATA already present, Please Enter different Date');
            }

            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $date_details = NimsoftHostsDetails::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('host_start_date'=>$model->host_end_date,'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
            if($date_details)
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('a', "The End date ".$model->host_end_date." is already mentioned as a start date");
                //$this->render('exist',array('message'=>"The End date ".$model->host_end_date." is already mentioned as a start date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
            die();

            }



            if($model->host_start_date == $model->host_end_date)
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('s', "Both dates same, Please Enter different Date");
                //$this->render('exist',array('message'=>"Both dates same, Please Enter different Date",'host_id'=>$model->host_id));
            die();
            }

        }
    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('host_id',$this->host_id);
        $criteria->compare('host_start_date',$this->host_start_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('host_end_date',$this->host_end_date,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return NimsoftHostsDetails the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

My view displays data, but in filtering part, If I input any text, its does not return anything. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the values you are using in your filter goes inside your model

```
public function search()
     {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('host_id',$this->host_id);
    $criteria->compare('host_start_date',$this->host_start_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('host_end_date',$this->host_end_date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

i'm having a hard time to read your code. So what field did you add to use as filter? is it by default included in your model?

Comment: I want to filter host_start_date, host_end_date

Comment: i dont really get It. Where are these filters included? is it in your grid view? Is it like searching or you want to display results that match your filter without using button submit?

Comment: In my Grid view, In the blank search box, If I enter any value, It must suggest similar records matching the input

Comment: I think you are using different data provider and model for your filter. Make sure they are the same model for your inputs to be used by the data provider to render filtered outputs.

Comment: data provider is correct, I am using the correct one

Comment: can anyone please help me on this

Comment: any one of the experts there?